# class attributes and recursion of function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, tree

I just solved problem on leetcode and I can't understand one thing in this code:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def maxDepth(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        if not root:
            return 0
        return 1 + max(self.maxDepth(root.left), self.maxDepth(root.right))
```

As I understand, root is a TreeNode object and that's why it should have all the attributes of TreeNode as `val`, `left`, `right`. In the last string we use attributes `left` and `right` of root. But when I wrote `if not root.val` it returned an error `Nonetype object has no attribute val`. Why in `return` we can use attributes of `root`, but we can't use `if not root.val`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not what you say. The code is not using the attributes of `root`, it is essentially querying `root`, asking: `"Are you a TreeNode, or None?"`.

If it is `None`, then it executes `return 0`.

If it is not `None`, *then* it must be a `TreeNode`, and then it *will* have the `left` and `right` attributes.

I'm sure that there may be many instances of `TreeNode` with attribute `val == 0`.

Comment: So, if I know that root is a TreeNode, I can write something like `print(root.val)`?

Comment: Yes, you can use attributes of `root` after the check.